# How can I implement vice versa mapping in Python?

Tags: python

I have to convert a bunch of strings into numbers, process the numbers and convert back.

I thought of a map where I will add 2 keys when I've provided string:

```
Key1: (string, number); 
Key2: (number, string).
```

But this is not optimal in terms of memory.

What I need to archieve in example:

```
my_cool_class.get('string') # outputs 1
my_cool_class.get(1)        # outputs 'string'
```

Is there better way to do this in python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the current status and what is the exactly output you need?

Comment: Status is actual - thinking about the problem now. What I exactly need: I need a class that can map strings and numbers vice versa. Example: my_cool_class.get('string') -> outputs 1; my_cool_class.get(1) -> outputs 'string'

Comment: hi @VladimirTsyshnatiy please use markdown for your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of allocate another memory for the second dict, you can get the key from the value, consider that it will cost you with run-time.

```
mydict = {'george':16,'amber':19}
print (mydict.keys()[mydict.values().index(16)])

>>> 'george'
```

**EDIT:**

Notice that In Python 3, dict.values() (along with dict.keys() and dict.items()) returns a view, rather than a list. You therefore need to wrap your call to dict.values() in a call to list like so:

```
mydict = {'george':16,'amber':19}
print (list(mydict.keys())[list(mydict.values()).index(16)])
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks!

Comment: Similar idea, but maybe a bit clearer: `next((k for k in d if d[k] == x), None)`

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own twoway dict like

```
class TwoWayDict(dict):
    def __len__(self):
        return dict.__len__(self) / 2

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        dict.__setitem__(self, value, key)

my_cool_class = TwoWayDict()
my_cool_class[1] = 'string'
print my_cool_class[1] # 'string'
print my_cool_class['string'] # 1
```

Comment: Yep, I thought about adding (key, value) and (value, key), but that consumes additional memory, so I've decided to ask you guys how to avoid this.

Comment: it depends on what is more critical to you: memory consumption or search complexity.

Comment: You are right, I think memory is more important now. But thanks for your help! I will definitely use your code if I change my vision.

Comment: This is one way to make sure that the mapping stays unique (two-way). If you only overload the `__getitem__` method you can create keys which have been stored as values already, thus destroying the two-way nature of the dict. One problem with this implementation is that it will not work if you construct your dict like this: `d = TwoWayDict({'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2})`. The mapping will not be created because `__setitem__` will not be called.

Answer (score 1):

If optimal memory usage is an issue, you may not want to use Python in the first place. To solve your immediate problem, just add both the string and the number as keys to the dictionary. Remember that only a reference to the original objects will be stored. Additional copies will not be made:

```
d = {}
s = '123'
n = int(s) 
d[s] = n
d[n] = s
```

Now you can access the value by the opposite key just like you wanted. This method has the advantage of `O(1)` lookup time.

Comment: If they are really copies then Nils Werner's answer works too. Great thanks to you!

Comment: @VladimirTsyshnatiy. Absolutely. His method is exactly like this except he adds both keys in one operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of tuples this way you just need to check against the type of the variable to decide which one you should return.
Example:

```
class your_cool_class(object):

    def __init__(self):
       # example of dictionary
       self.your_dictionary = {'3': ('3', 3), '4': ('4', 4)}

    def get(self, numer):
        is_string = isinstanceof(number, str)
        number = str(number)
        n = self.your_dictionary.get(number)
        if n is not None:
            return n[0] if is_string else n[1]


>>>> my_cool_class = your_cool_class()
>>>> my_cool_class.get(3)
>>>> '3'
>>>> my_cool_class.get('3')
>>>> 3
```